# Commit test with the cvsClient api return false

Tags: java, api, cvs

I have this code :

```
package fr.cnamts.navigo.cvs;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.CVSRoot;
import org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.Client;
import org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.admin.StandardAdminHandler;
import org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.command.CommandAbortedException;
import org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.command.CommandException;
import org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.command.GlobalOptions;
import org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.command.commit.CommitCommand;
import org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.connection.AuthenticationException;
import org.netbeans.lib.cvsclient.connection.PServerConnection;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class CvsCommandTest {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(CvsCommandTest.class);
    private final String cvsroot = ":pserver:name:password@host.fr:2401/cvsdata/BUS-2010";

    private final String localPath = "/cvsdata/BUS-2010";
    private final File f = new File(
            "d:/projets/bus/workspaceJhipster/navigo/src/main/resources/logback.xml");
    private final File[] files = new File[1];

    @Test
    public void test() {
        CVSRoot root = CVSRoot.parse(cvsroot);

        PServerConnection con = new PServerConnection(root);
        // con.setUserName(user);
        // con.setEncodedPassword(StandardScrambler.getInstance().scramble(
        // password));

        GlobalOptions globalOptions = new GlobalOptions();
        globalOptions.setCVSRoot(root.toString());

        Client client = new Client(con, new StandardAdminHandler());

        // this line is important, because otherwise you'll get a
        // NullpointerException!
        client.setLocalPath(localPath);
        files[0] = f;

        LOG.info("COMMITING");

        CommitCommand commitCmd = new CommitCommand();
        commitCmd.setBuilder(null);
        commitCmd.setRecursive(true);
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            LOG.info("- " + files[i].getAbsolutePath());
        }
        commitCmd.setFiles(files);
        commitCmd.setToRevisionOrBranch("testTag");

        try {
            client.getConnection().open();
            LOG.info("CVS COMMAND: " + commitCmd.getCVSCommand());
            boolean success = client.executeCommand(commitCmd, globalOptions);
            LOG.info("COMMIT COMPLETED : " + success);
            client.getConnection().close();
        } catch (CommandAbortedException cae) {
            LOG.error("Probleme CommandAbortedException : " + cae.getMessage());
        } catch (AuthenticationException ae) {
            LOG.error("Probleme AuthenticationException : " + ae.getMessage());
        } catch (CommandException ce) {
            LOG.error("Probleme CommandException : " + ce.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            LOG.error("Probleme IOException : " + ioe.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

success is false :

> [INFO] fr.cnamts.navigo.cvs.CvsCommandTest - COMMITING [INFO]
>   fr.cnamts.navigo.cvs.CvsCommandTest - -
>   d:\projets\bus\workspaceJhipster\navigo\src\main\resources\logback.xml
>   [INFO] fr.cnamts.navigo.cvs.CvsCommandTest - CVS COMMAND: commit -r
>   testTag logback.xml  [INFO] fr.cnamts.navigo.cvs.CvsCommandTest -
>   COMMIT COMPLETED : false

but I don't know why it fails. Is there a way to find why it fails?

Answer (score 0):

To add a listener follow the steps described [here](https://versioncontrol.netbeans.org/javacvs/library/GettingStarted.html) in the "Listening" section. It displays information message from cvs to the user.